# Using Subprocess.call I want to run an executable from another program

Tags: python

I have a command line executable that I want to call with subprocess.call. The call itself to the application works.

`subprocess.call(['filepathIEF.exe'], shell=True)`.  This part works fine.

I want to automate this command:

```
IEF.exe --image [image path] -- search [type] --output [output path]
```

When I broke it down by pieces, IEF.exe works fine, then I got a -1 error when I added the

```
'--image', 'Filepathofimage'], shell=True)
```

I then tried adding each piece of this CLI and received an error of 1, then, I tried placing the whole line in one '' and I received the error of 1. I only started using Python about 2 months ago and I still have much to learn. I also tried the Popen and it returned an error of

When this command is run in the CLI, it generates a set of files inside the file I name as the output. I could really use some assistance on this.  I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I'm not seeing it.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subprocess.call the Popen command works.

command = ['c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Evidence Finder\IEF.exe', '--image', 'C:\Users\examiner\Documents\IEFTest\UbuntuTest.001', '--search', 'quick', '--output', 'c:\Users\examiner\Documents\IEFTest\CommandLineTest\UbuntuTest4']

subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: command = ['c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Evidence Finder\\IEF.exe', '--image', 'C:\Users\\examiner\\Documents\\IEFTest\\UbuntuTest.001', '--search', 'quick', '--output', 'c:\\Users\\examiner\\Documents\\IEFTest\\CommandLineTest\\UbuntuTest4']

subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the commas, brackets, and inner quotes. `shell=True` means you are passing the command and arguments as a string and not as a list.

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Andrew. Ok, I removed the shell=True and the commas. When I did that and selected return, I got Traceback errors. subprocess.call(['c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Evidence Finder\IEF.exe'  '--image' 'J:\IEFTest\IEFTest001.E01' '--search' 'quick' '--output' 'J:\IEFTest\CommandLineTest\WindowsTest2'] is the command I'm trying to run.  I want the files to generate to the WindowsTest2 Folder. I also tried removing the quotes around the J:\IEFTest\IEFTest001.EO1 and received an syntax error on the J drive.

Comment: My answer was actually kind of unclear.  But either way, you can't take out `shell=True` and remove the commas. I'm going to edit my answer, but consider reviewing list syntax. Once `shell=True` is removed you need to pass the arguments as a list. I would use this: `subprocess.call("c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Evidence Finder\IEF.exe --image J:\IEFTest\IEFTest001.E01 --search quick --output J:\IEFTest\CommandLineTest\WindowsTest2", shell=True)`

Comment: Ok, thank you Andrew. I tried it but still got the return of 1. I'll review the list syntax again.  Thank you for your help. I'm attempting to learn this in a very short period of time, and I know only practice will make it better. Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the list of arguments without `shell=True` like Daniel suggested? I've always had bad luck with that in linux but it might work better in windows. In that case you would use `subprocess.call(['c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Evidence Finder\IEF.exe', '--image', 'J:\IEFTest\IEFTest001.E01', '--search', 'quick', '--output', 'J:\IEFTest\CommandLineTest\WindowsTest2'])`

Comment: I did remove it. I also tried it the way you typed it. I still got the error of -1.  This may just be a command that I can't use the subprocess module for. I'll see if there is another way to do it. Thank you again!

Comment: Good afternoon everyone, I'm still having some issues with this. I've been researching this and trying to find a way to write this so all of the commands will execute. Would this be better if I used os.system rather than the subprocess? I can get the executable to run using python's subprocess.call but as soon as I add the other arguments it breaks. I'm also looking at pexpect as an additional option or method. Thank you all for your assistance. I'm just looking for the best way to get python to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `shell=True`. It's unnecessary.

```
subprocess.call(['filepath/IEF.exe', '--image', image_filename])
```